# The VisualStateManager does not change UserControl's Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, responsive-design, windows-10-universal

Please help me to understand why the VisualStateManager does not change 
UserControls Visibility on window resizing.
I want to substitute one usercontrol with another one when the window is resizing.

Here is my code:

```
<Page
x:Class="Diagrams.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Diagrams"
xmlns:uc="using:Diagrams.UserControls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ContentControl>
        <StackPanel>
        <uc:MyUserControl1 x:Name="MyControl1" Visibility="Visible" Height="400" Width="900" />
        <uc:MyUserControl1 x:Name="MyControl2" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="400" Width="900"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </ContentControl>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState  x:Name="Narrow">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Target="MyControl2.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Setter Target="MyControl1.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter Target="MyControl1.Background" Value="Black" />

                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState  x:Name="WideScreen">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1080" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="Blue" />
                    <Setter Target="MyControl2.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter Target="MyControl1.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Setter Target="MyControl1.Background" Value="Red" />

                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Surface">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1921" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="Black" />
                    <Setter Target="MyControl2.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Setter Target="MyControl1.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter Target="MyControl1.Background" Value="Yellow" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

</Grid>
```

Comment: the sample code you provided works fine for me. Maybe you don't have enough screen resolution to trigger the 1080px trigger? Can you change them to 600 and 800 or something  and test?

Comment: The RootGrid is changing its Background, so reolution is can't be the reason, UserControls are my problem.

Comment: As @AlexDrenea said it works fine, the value of MyControl1.Background has changed too. But there is no effect in the screen.

Comment: Are you testing it under Windows Universal ?